# how to write this properly

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

requestoptions ={method : "POST",
credentials: 'same-origin',
header :{"Content-Type":"application/json"},
body: JSON.stringify(Cookies.get("refreshtok")}

}

***body: JSON.stringify(Cookies.get("refreshtok")} says expected "," in this line***

Comment: What is your problem? Describe it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the closing parenthesis from `JSON.stringify`:

```js
    requestoptions = {
        method : "POST", 
        credentials: 'same-origin', 
        header: {
            "Content-Type":"application/json"
        }, 
        body: JSON.stringify(Cookies.get("refreshtok"))
     }
```

Comment: Thanks maaaaaan. I was thinking i am stupid , but now i feel the same just for another reason -_-.